# Javascript. Applied method do not see method from base function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function:

```
function method($scope, $timeout, shLoadCountryService) 
{
    function getDate(){
         /somecode
    }
    $scope.submit = function (userResponse, parameters)
    {
        getDate();
        //code
    }
    shLoadCountryService.loadCountry(arguments.callee.name, arguments);
}

function customized_method($scope, $timeout, shLoadCountryService) 
{
    $scope.submit = function (userResponse, parameters)
    {
        getDate();
        //code
    }
}

angular.module("mobile")
    .factory("shLoadCountryService", ["shMainScopeService", function (shMainScopeService) {
        var self = this;
        function loadCountry(name, params) {
            var methodName = shMainScopeService.scope.product + '_' + name;
            if (typeof window[methodName] === "function") {
                window[methodName].apply(this, params);
            }
        };
        self.loadCountry = loadCountry;
        return self;
    }]
);
```

If  scope.product is set then submit should be replaced from `customized_method()` This part work. But inside the submit method we call `getDate()` which is defined in base function.

When running this I'm getting `ReferenceError: getTodayDate is not defined`

Is there any way to apply function from second function and still be able to use functions from base?

Comment: why cant you declare getDate() outside the first method`s scope?

Comment: I know that if I will put this function on scope this will work but i was asked if there is any other possibility. If know I will put it on the scope.

Comment: i don't think so since you declare the function inside the scope of the first method, the second method is unaware of the function...